# How to install py2app

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, py2app

I have been coding with Python for a couple moths now and I have come across the stage where I want to turn my python scripts into stand alone programs. I am running Python 3.4 and default Python 2.7 that was pre installed on my mac. I am running os x 10.9.5. I have heard about a tool called py2app but i have no idea how to install it and use it. I have seen many other tutorials but they are useless; 1. most of them are windows based 2. they are not related to my problem. A detailed answer with step by step instructions on how to install and use py2app would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Officail Installation [page](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/install.html#installing-with-easy-install):

> Open your Mac Terminal 
>   To install py2app using easy_install you must make sure you have a
>   recent version of distribute installed (as of this writing, 0.6b4 or
>   later):
>
> $ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py 
>   
>  $ python
>   ez_setup.py -U distribute
>
> To install or upgrade to the latest released version of py2app:
>
> $ easy_install -U py2app
>
> If you install into a system installation of Python you might need
>   additional privileges, you can use the sudo commando to get those:
>
> $ sudo easy_install -U py2app

Comment: When i tried your installation method it came up with this error: error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-324.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: @Amedeo You have to be a super user to do this, so run `su` and enter your password, then follow the steps above.